# Choropleth map with plotly error: invalid figure_or_data argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly

I'd like to use plotly to construct a choropleth map. I have a dataframe with the state codes and a count that looks like this:

```
  count state
0   1   AK
1   9   AL
2   2   AR
3   11  AZ
4   31  CA
...
```

I've tried the following:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

test_data = [dict(type='choropleth',
                 autocolorscale=False,
                 locations=df['state'],
                 z=df['count'],
                 locationmode='USA-states',
                 marker=dict(
                     line=dict(
                         color='rgb(255,255,255)',
                         width=2
                     )),
                 colorbar=dict(
                     title='Choropleth Map Test')
                 )] 
layout = dict(
            title='Test title',
            geo = dict(
                scope='usa',
            projection=dict(type='albers usa'),
            snowflakes=True,
            lakecolor='rgb(255,255,255)'),
            )

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig,filename='d3-cloropleth-map')
```

Then I get an error:

```
PlotlyDictValueError: 'data' has invalid value inside 'figure'
Path To Error: ['data']
Current path: []
Current parent object_names: []
Additionally:
    role: object
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try `data=[data]` instead of `data=data` in your fig definition at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

> from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, **iplot**

You've already imported iplot from plotly.offline and should call the function directly. Use iplot() instead of py.iplot().

py appears to be defined as something else that is not included in the code you've listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Code below should work:

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

**Create sample data**

```
state = ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA']
count = [1,9,2,11,31]
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':state, 'count':count})
df.head(2)
```

**Code below is from the question above**

Note: `snowflakes=True` is `commented out`

```
test_data = [dict(type='choropleth',
                 autocolorscale=False,
                 locations=df['state'],
                 z=df['count'],
                 locationmode='USA-states',
                 marker=dict(
                     line=dict(
                         color='rgb(255,255,255)',
                         width=2
                     )),
                 colorbar=dict(
                     title='Choropleth Map Test')
                 )] 
layout = dict(
            title='Test title',
            geo = dict(
                scope='usa',
                projection=dict(type='albers usa'),
                #snowflakes=True,
                lakecolor='rgb(255,255,255)'),
            )

fig = dict(data=test_data, layout=layout)

pyo.iplot(fig,filename='d3-cloropleth-map')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# Code works, but no MAP

Must Restart and run all

!pip install cufflinks
!pip install chart_studio

import chart_studio
import pandas as pd
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import cufflinks as cf


init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()



# scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
#             [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]

#Create sample data

state = ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA']
count = [1,9,2,11,31]
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':state, 'count':count})
#df.head(2)
#Code below is from the question above

#Note: snowflakes=True is commented out

test_data = [dict(type='choropleth',
                 autocolorscale=False,
                 locations=df['state'],
                 z=df['count'],
                 locationmode='USA-states',
                 marker=dict(
                     line=dict(
                         color='rgb(255,255,255)',
                         width=2
                     )),
                 colorbar=dict(
                     title='Choropleth Map Test')
                 )] 
layout = dict(
            title='Test title',
            geo = dict(
                scope='usa',
                projection=dict(type='albers usa'),
                #snowflakes=True,
                lakecolor='rgb(255,255,255)'),
            )

fig = dict(data=test_data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig,filename='d3-cloropleth-map')
```

Answer (score 0):

plotly could be the problem... try installing this way:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org plotly
```